# Setup dependent Maven Java projects so changes are pickedup right away without run maven install

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have two Maven Java projects in Eclipse.  I added Project B is a dependency in Project A's pom.xml file.  Each time a code change is made to Project B, I have to do 'run maven install' on B, and then do a 'maven update project' on A, in order for the changes to appear in A.  Is there a better/faster yet proper way to manage this?

I have tried to remove the maven dependency in A's pom.xml and use Eclipse's the project dependency, that result in class not found error when I try to run A.

Comment: Use m2eclipse's Workspace Dependency Management.

Comment: One word: Gradle https://gradle.org/maven-vs-gradle/

Answer (score 1):

You can add "Refresh Resources" -> Entire Workspace after completion in your Maven Run Configuration

Comment: You mean to add 'refresh source' during the 'run maven install' on B?  That will eliminate the step of running 'maven update project' on A.  But is there an even better way?  Let say I have a few more projects, C, D, E, F that A depends on, if there are code changes in any of them (and I dont know which one), then I will need to do 'run maven install' on all of them.  Is there a way for A to automatically pick up changes from all of its dependent projects in one shot?

Comment: It's a bit different nature of Maven: it manages on artifacts level from repository but not for source. Let's say if you run clean install on project D as a SNAPSHOT, and your project A rely on SNAPSHOT as well. Maven would be able to resolve it accordingly. Unfortunately, it's not so perfect in Eclipse itself and it could have lags. But I notice the same kind of problems with Gradle too. It's not a silver bullet to move in